# Dynamic list attribute retrieval

Tags: r, list, attributes

Let's say there is this list:

```
> l <- list( foo = "bar")
> l
$foo
[1] "bar"
```

if there is an attribute name as a string in a variable

```
> field <- "foo"
```

How can I get this attribute dynamically?

This works:

```
> "$"(l, 'foo')
[1] "bar"
```

This does not:

```
> "$"(l, field)
NULL
```

Even if casted it `as.symbol` still no luck:

```
> "$"(l, as.symbol(field))
Error in l$as.symbol(field) : invalid subscript type 'language'
> field <- as.symbol(field)
> "$"(l, field)
NULL
```

How can I force the interpretation of the `field` variable contents so I can retrieve dynamically the attribute value of the list?

Comment: ? What is wrong with using `l[[field]]` ?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just quite new with R :) . Can I make this somehow work? Is there the two methods somehow different?

Comment: They're the same, use `[[stringcontainingthename]]` instead of `$name` and you'll get the same results ;)

Comment: Try `"["(l, field)`

Comment: @zx8754: single '[' will return a list

Comment: @digEmAll correct, then let's use double: `"[["(l, field)`